# Timezone question for list items?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, date-time

I have a sharepoint which is accessed and modified by different people around the world. So when ever a list item is created in the sharepoint the list item modified date should contain that locations timezone.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with code where you can change timezone based on current user login. You need to add custom feature on home page so code could identify current time zone and set proper regional settings for current application across the site.

```
    var loggedInUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
if (user.RegionalSettings != null)
{
return user.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
}
else
{
// User has not set a time zone, so use the one set for the Web
return SPContext.Current.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
}
```

Check this for more details: http://www.stum.de/2010/06/10/dealing-with-multiple-time-zones-in-sharepoint-2010/

Another way to deal with it.

http://sp2010ashish.blogspot.com/2011/09/time-zone-for-sharepoint-user.html
http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/Time-Zones-in-SharePoint

Comment: I am still a novice in SharePoint. So where exactly do you insert this code in?